# Permanently saving the value of a string

Tags: java, string

I am currently making a flash card program, and I want the user to be able to put in their own questions and answers, then test themselves. My only problem is that i want the values they enter to be there **permanently** until changed by them. How do I do this? (P.S: if you need the code, I can give it.)

Comment: we would like the code

Comment: How permanent? You could save the `String`s to a file, so that even if the program is closed, they are still there. Or if you want less permanence, you could store the `String`s in some list.

Comment: Other then a file the only thing that springs to mind would be a database to store information

Comment: I concur, if you wish to persist the data from instance to instance, you will need to store it in either a file or a database.

Comment: the only way is to store perminantely data into file or DB s/ws..

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are new to programming and you have not yet worked with persistence of any context. In this case, for your simple example, the Java [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class might be a good entry point into the field of file persistence.

In general, there are plenty of ways to persist data: databases, files, web storage, etc... It depends on your application and what you want to do with the data. For an example of the Java `Properties` file see for example this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Well without seeing any of the code, it is hard to tell you exactly how you should approach this, but in general you will need some method of persistence to save this type of information, ie. a database, flat file, etc. Try looking into sqlite or even XML for storage and retrieval.